# Nested select to count items and sum them in new columns in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a following table in MS Access and would like to get count in one table as displayed below. Grouped by system and two columns counting the Locked/Unlocked status.

```
|SYSTEM|LOCK_STAT|
------------------
|A     |Locked   |
|A     |Unlocked |
|A     |Locked   |
|B     |Locked   |
|B     |Unlocked |
|B     |Unlocked |
```

And the result should be as follows:

```
|SYSTEM|UNLOCKED|LOCKED|
| A    |       1|     2|
| B    |       2|     1|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IIF()` for conditional aggregation:

```
select
  SYSTEM,
  sum(iif(lock_stat = 'Unlocked', 1, 0)) as UNLOCKED,
  sum(iif(lock_stat = 'Locked', 1, 0)) as LOCKED
from tablename
group by SYSTEM
```

or sum the boolean conditions and since `TRUE` is converted to `-1`, get their absolute values:

```
select
  SYSTEM,
  abs(sum(lock_stat = 'Unlocked')) as UNLOCKED,
  abs(sum(lock_stat = 'Locked')) as LOCKED
from tablename
group by SYSTEM
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a crosstab query, such as:

```
transform count(*) select t.system from YourTable t group by t.system pivot t.lock_stat;
```

Change `YourTable` to your table name.